# Find n characters before file extension

Tags: regex

Need some help with regex

I want to keep the last n characters (eg. 4 characters) from a file name not including the file extension

For example if I have the filename

"thisisapicture.jpg"

At the moment I am using something like

```
\w+(?=\.\w+$)
```

to capture everything before the file extension. What if I want to capture only the last 4 characters e.g. *ture* before the file extension?

thanks

Comment: A useful tool to try out and debug your expression: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a quantifier `\w{4}` instead of `\w+`:

```
\w{4}(?=\.\w+$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mX8aF/1)

Comment: if my filename has spaces and parentheses e.g. _this is a file (f).jpg_ and I want to capture only _a file (f)_ ?

Comment: If you want to match the last 2 words followed by a space you could try https://regex101.com/r/HPXCXV/1

Answer (score 0):

Since you need only four characters before the dot, you need to capture it into group:

```
var s = "thisisapicture.jpg";
var pattern = @"(.{4})\.\w+$";
var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```